# Running multiple functions on a python selenium script

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am fairly new to writing python scripts and I wanted to know how to make different `def` functions work simultaniously, I have this following code:

```
class gameBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        (basically logs into the game with username and password)

def moving_on(self, cronometer, energy, no_energy):
        (checks if energy is able to refill and refills automatically)

bot = gameBot(username, password)
bot.moving_on(cronometer, energy, no_energy)
```

so what I wanted to understand is that if I had multiple `def` functions (let's say one for energy refill as shown above, other for sending a message in the game etc etc) how do I get them to run at the same time and in a never-ending loop? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running in same time you have to use

multiprocessing or threading modules of python

And use while loop for never ending loop